# using jQuery how to consume REST based WCF web service to upload file

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, rest

Here's how to Web Service method looks like:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class FileUploadService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{folder}/{fileName}", Method = "POST")]
    public void UploadFile(string folder, string fileName, Stream fileContents)
    {
        // Code removed for brevity. Basically we are reading the fileContents into FileStream and saving it on server.

    }
}
```

I am able to write a small .NET application and consume this Web service. My question is how do I consume it from jQuery? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

//Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using Stream and consume it from javascript. You can use HTML5 FileReader API to upload the file. - Example - http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-upload-multiple-files-with-html5-and-jquery/